# Disable specific color in todonotes

Tags: todonotes

I'm using the todonotes package for a large writing project. I have a system with different colored notes for different purposes, for example orange is notes for myself, while yellow is bigger ideas that my collaborators should look at.

Is there a way to disable one or more colors so they are hidden when compiling? This way I can send a version to collaborators in which "my own todos" are gone, but the big questions are still there. Something like:

```
\usepackage[disable=orange]{todonotes}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Which one do you want to hide: a subset of todos sharing a same color, or just the color and keep all the todos typeset. May be better illustrated with a complete example.

Comment: I want to hide the todos that have a specific color, while typesetting all the other colored todos as normal. Perhaps it's better to not talk about the colors, that's just the way I differentiate the todos at the moment. Perhaps it better to instead say I want to have two (or more) sets of todos that can be enabled or disabled independently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define two commands, one to use for notes by yourself (`\NoteToMe` in this example) and one to use for great ideas. Each with its own options.

When you want to send your document to your collaborators, activate the option `disable` in the definition of  `\NoteToMe`

Working document: all notes are shown

[image: a]

Document to share: only with great ideas

[image: b]

Using

```
\newcommand{\NoteToMe}[1]{\todo[linecolor=linecolor,
    backgroundcolor=bkgcolor,
    bordercolor=bordercolor,
    textcolor=textcolor,
    disable % activate to disable <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
]{#1}}
```

Complete code

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage[left=3.00cm, right=5.00cm, top=4.00cm, bottom=3.00cm, marginparwidth=4cm]{geometry}


\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{xcolor}

%  colors to myself
\definecolor{textcolor}{RGB}{255,69,0}
\definecolor{bordercolor}{RGB}{0,0,0}
\definecolor{linecolor}{RGB}{150,0,0}
\definecolor{bkgcolor}{RGB}{254,254, 254}

% great colors for others to see
\definecolor{greattextcolor}{RGB}{10,215, 50}
\definecolor{greatbordercolor}{RGB}{100,100,100}
\definecolor{greatlinecolor}{RGB}{150,0,0}
\definecolor{greatbkgcolor}{RGB}{254,254, 254}

\newcommand{\NoteToMe}[1]{\todo[linecolor=linecolor,
    backgroundcolor=bkgcolor,
    bordercolor=bordercolor,
    textcolor=textcolor,
    %disable % activate to disable <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
]{#1}}

\newcommand{\GreatIdea}[1]{\todo[linecolor=greattextcolor,
    backgroundcolor=greatbkgcolor,
    bordercolor=greatbordercolor,
    textcolor=greattextcolor
    ]{#1}}


\usepackage{kantlipsum} % only to dummy text

\begin{document}

\kant[1]\NoteToMe{Let us suppose that the noumena have nothing to do
with necessity, since knowledge of the Categories is a
posteriori.}

\kant[2]\GreatIdea{\textbf{GREAT!} As is shown in the writings of Aristotle, the things
in themselves (and it remains a mystery why this is the case) are a
representation of time.}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Both this and Marijin's solution does what I asked for, but I think this is more clean, and can be extended more easily to have other groups of todos that work independently. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can add a check to the handling of the color argument, as follows:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage[left=3.00cm, right=5.00cm, top=4.00cm, bottom=3.00cm, marginparwidth=4cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\def\discolor{green}
\makeatletter
\define@key{todonotes}{color}{%
\renewcommand{\@todonotes@currentlinecolor}{#1}%
\renewcommand{\@todonotes@currentbackgroundcolor}{#1}%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{\discolor}}{\@todonotes@localdisabletrue}{}%
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{kantlipsum} % only for dummy text

\begin{document}

\kant[1]\todo[color=green]{Let us suppose that the noumena have nothing to do
with necessity, since knowledge of the Categories is a
posteriori.}

\kant[2]\todo{\textbf{GREAT!} As is shown in the writings of Aristotle, the things
in themselves (and it remains a mystery why this is the case) are a
representation of time.}

\end{document}
```

Now by defining the `\discolor` command you can choose which color is disabled.